# Iterating to change each value in a Ruby hash one at a time

Tags: ruby, recursion, hash

I have a problem whereby I want to:

1-iterate through a nested hash, so which can have arrays, hashes, or a value etc
2-for each value i find replace this with a string "text", but only one a time, so for each iteration only that one value is changed and the rest of the hash is intact
3-use this new hash in a function

The problem is that when i do this recursively I either only get partial hashes back since the recursive function has no idea of the wider context, or I get the original hash back with all values changed instead of just one, but I can't think of doing it without recursion either

Is what I'm asking possible?

Thanks

edit: ok people want me to post code and downvoting me even though all i asked was if the concept was possible and not for a solution!! but whatever here's my most recent attempt, but it's been mostly just trial and error to see what sticks so it clearly won't be on the right track if all i'm asking is if it's possible with recursion:

what I'm trying to do is recursively find values to change, and remember the map to them as i do so i can use that trail of breadcrumbs to change the original hash

```
def iterate_and_test_within_hash endpoint, hashbody, teststrings
p "#{hashbody}"
for payload in teststrings do
outhash=scrolltests hashbody, nil, hashbody, payload
end
end

def scrolltests parenthash, parentkeys, hashin, teststring
  if !parentkeys
  parentkeys=[]
 end
 # outhash=Marshal.load( Marshal.dump(parenthash) )
 outhash=parenthash
# localparentkeys=Marshal.load( Marshal.dump(parentkeys) )


p parentkeys
    hashin.each do |k, v|
  if v.is_a?(String) || v.is_a?(Numeric)

    parentkeys.concat([k])
    p parentkeys
    parentkeys.map!(&:to_sym)
    key = parentkeys.pop

    begin

      parentkeys.inject(outhash, :fetch)[key] = teststring
    rescue => e
        key = parentkeys.pop
      retry
    end

    p outhash
    parentkeys.concat([k])
    scrolltests(parenthash, parentkeys,v, teststring)
  elsif v.is_a?(Array)
      v.flatten.each { |x|
        if x.is_a?(Hash)
          # parentkeys.concat([x])
          scrolltests(parenthash, parentkeys,x, teststring)
        end
        }
  end
end
end


with this input hash:
{
      :properties=>{
          :one=>'extra',
          :headers=>{
              :type=>'object',
              :type1=>'object2'
          },
          :entity=>{
              :type=>'entype'
          },
      },
      :sec_prop=>'hmmm'
  }
```

it gives these results, so the keys aren't being tracked correctly between recursions i suspect as some elements are put into the wrong levels, put under parents where they dont' have a parent but previous element did, also elements on the same hierarchial level are being changed at the same time

```
[]
[:properties]
[:properties, :one]
{:properties=>{:one=>"<PLAINTEXT>", :headers=>{:type=>"object", :type1=>"object2"}, :entity=>{:type=>"entype"}}, :sec_prop=>"hmmm"}
[:properties, :headers]
[:properties, :headers, :type]
{:properties=>{:one=>"extra", :headers=>{:type=>"<PLAINTEXT>", :type1=>"object2"}, :entity=>{:type=>"entype"}}, :sec_prop=>"hmmm"}
[:properties, :headers, :type1]
{:properties=>{:one=>"extra", :headers=>{:type=>"<PLAINTEXT>", :type1=>"<PLAINTEXT>"}, :entity=>{:type=>"entype"}}, :sec_prop=>"hmmm"}
[:properties, :headers, :entity]
[:properties, :headers, :entity, :type]
{:properties=>{:one=>"extra", :headers=>{:type=>"object", :type1=>"object2", :entity=>"<PLAINTEXT>"}, :entity=>{:type=>"entype"}}, :sec_prop=>"hmmm"}
[:properties, :sec_prop]
{:properties=>{:one=>"extra", :headers=>{:type=>"object", :type1=>"object2"}, :entity=>{:type=>"entype"}, :sec_prop=>"<PLAINTEXT>"}, :sec_prop=>"hmmm"}
```

Comment: Please [read this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question. In particular, please post your code ([edit your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40104741/edit)) so that we can properly understand your problem.

Comment: Post your code please, Otherwise how can anyone understand what you are asking?

Comment: Specify input and output specifically so that the people who want to work can easily do their Job.

Comment: Well i'll post code ok, but i was asking if it's possible not for a solution

Comment: you have to post the code to know whether it's possible or not as well. If you give program, it's easy to understand.

Comment: i don't see how posting code can help, because the code clearly wont be the solution if i don't even know if the problem is solvable yet. this was a bad idea.

Comment: @alsandair  it is hard to visualize your problem with the current information. Maybe the other guys ask you to give more details. Maybe the example of the hash and the example of the expected hash.

Comment: ah thanks bekicot ok here's what i'd like as outputs, I'm wondering is hash.merge or hash.update within the recursive func might help:

hash 1: {one: "stringa", two: "stringb"}

| after first run: {one: "TEST", two: "stringb"}

| after 2nd run:
 {one: "stringa", two: "TEST"}

...where the values changed can possibly be nested within other hashes in hash1, so one value changed each time, but the rest of the hash unchanged

Answer (score 0):

solved it (apart from for arrays or hashes at the moment)  in case anyone has a similar issue. big problems for me where that i had to get it to remember how it got to a particular "layer" of recursion to map where it should be writing to the main hash, and that ruby passes by reference not object, which means when travelling in a tree-like object, one branch will screw the parameters for the next branch

code:

```
def scrolltests parenthash, parentkeys, hashin, teststring
  keys=Marshal.load( Marshal.dump(parentkeys) )

hashin.each do |k, v|
  if !keys
    keys=[]
  end
  keys.to_a

  outhash=Marshal.load( Marshal.dump(parenthash) )

  p keys
  if v.is_a?(String) || v.is_a?(Numeric)
    keys.concat([k])
      p keys
    keys.map!(&:to_sym)
      key = keys.pop
      begin
        keys.inject(outhash, :fetch)[key] = teststring
      rescue => e
        key =keys.pop
        retry
      end

    # end

    p outhash

  elsif v.is_a?(Hash)
    keys.concat([k])
      scrolltests(parenthash, keys,v, teststring)
    keys.pop

  elsif v.is_a?(Array)
      v.flatten.each { |x|
        if x.is_a?(Hash)
          scrolltests(parenthash, keys,x, teststring)
        end
        }
  end



end


end
```

so that with an input test hash/json of

```
{
  :properties=>{
      :one=>'extra',
      :headers=>{
          :type=>'object',
          :type1=>'object2'
      },
      :entity=>{
          :type=>'entype'
      },
  },
  :sec_prop=>'hmmm'
  }
```

the output shows individually changing each element like so:

```
"{:properties=>{:one=>\"extra\", :headers=>{:type=>\"object\", :type1=>\"object2\"}, :entity=>{:type=>\"entype\"}}, 


{:properties=>{:one=>"<PLAINTEXT>", :headers=>{:type=>"object", :type1=>"object2"}, :entity=>{:type=>"entype"}}, :sec_prop=>"hmmm"}

{:properties=>{:one=>"extra", :headers=>{:type=>"<PLAINTEXT>", :type1=>"object2"}, :entity=>{:type=>"entype"}}, :sec_prop=>"hmmm"}

{:properties=>{:one=>"extra", :headers=>{:type=>"object", :type1=>"<PLAINTEXT>"}, :entity=>{:type=>"entype"}}, :sec_prop=>"hmmm"}

{:properties=>{:one=>"extra", :headers=>{:type=>"object", :type1=>"object2"}, :entity=>{:type=>"<PLAINTEXT>"}}, :sec_prop=>"hmmm"}

{:properties=>{:one=>"extra", :headers=>{:type=>"object", :type1=>"object2"}, :entity=>{:type=>"entype"}}, :sec_prop=>"<PLAINTEXT>"}
```